# yii\base\UnknownMethodException error when trying to $model->save() with yii2 non-table model

Tags: yii2-model

I'm getting Calling unknown method: app\modules\employee\models\NewEmployeeForm::save() error when trying to do $model->save();

I assumed save() method is inherited from Model, but then this happened. Do I need to write my own save method? I want to follow the yii2 way of doing things.

below is my model

thanks in advance

```
use common\models\User;
use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;

/**
 * Signup form
 */
class NewEmployeeForm extends Model
{
    public $nik;
    public $pin;
    public $company_id;
    public $category_id;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;



    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
         [['pin', 'company_id', 'category_id'], 'integer'],
         [['nik'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
         [['first_name', 'last_name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }


}
```

Comment: in case anyone reading this misses, the model above is not a database-table based model

Comment: You need validate function, not save

Comment: I just realize how dumb i was. the form-model was intended to capture form-input for two table-based models (employee & profile). I just now realise that nowhere in my model definition tells yii to save the values into table-based models.

Comment: @stig-js why? shouldn't i need both?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was thinking in the contactForm example